# python: hybrid between regular method and classmethod

Tags: python, methods, decorator, python-decorators, class-method

sometimes I have need to write class with static methods,
however with possibility to initialized it and keep state (object)

sth like:

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def method(cls_or_self):
    # get reference to object when A().method() or to class when A.method()
    code
```

what I have now is:

```
class A:
   def method(self = None, *params): code
   # or
   def method2(self = None, **params): code
   # but what I need is rather normal parameters, not optional and named args:
   def method3(self_or_cls, a, b=1, c=2, *p, **kw): code
```

please do not write about differences between staticmethod and classmethod. I am interested if such decorator exists (in more or less standard libs) and moreover if above is suitable for PEP.

Comment: You mean a hybrid between a classmethod and a *regular* method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Functions and `classmethod` objects act as [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html); both return a wrapper that when called will in turn call the underlying function with an extra parameter. The only difference between how functions and `classmethod` objects behave is in what that extra parameter *is*.

To create a hybrid of the two approaches, build your own descriptor decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

class hybridmethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        context = obj if obj is not None else cls

        @wraps(self.func)
        def hybrid(*args, **kw):
            return self.func(context, *args, **kw)

        # optional, mimic methods some more
        hybrid.__func__ = hybrid.im_func = self.func
        hybrid.__self__ = hybrid.im_self = context

        return hybrid
```

Here, we return a wrapper that'll use either the class or the instance as the first parameter, depending on what is available when the descriptor `__get__` method is called.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @hybridmethod
...     def bar(cls_or_self):
...         print 'Called with cls_or_self={!r}'.format(cls_or_self)
... 
>>> Foo.bar()
Called with cls_or_self=<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo().bar()
Called with cls_or_self=<__main__.Foo object at 0x1043a4390>
```

Comment: ... such fast and amazing that I must wait to accept answer (stackoverflow reqs), but what about classmethod ? - for me above decorator looks much functional, even to suggest overwrite the clasmethod or add third standard decorator for methods. I know it require strong criticism.

Comment: The `classmethod` decorator serves a different goal; methods that are ambiguous about their behaviour (act one way or another based on context) are not too pythonic.